# Serializing entity to XML - add method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datacontractserializer

Can anybody help me with the below?

**Models**

```
public class Integer
{
    public int IntegerID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter an integer")]
    [Integer(ErrorMessage = "Enter an integer")]
    public int IntegerValue { get; set; }
    public int IntegerListID { get; set; }

    public virtual IntegerList IntegerList { get; set; }
}

public class IntegerList
{ 
    public int IntegerListID { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
    public long Performance { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Integer> Integers { get; set; }

    public IntegerList()
    {
        Integers = new List<Integer>();
    }
}
```

**Controller Action**

```
    public ActionResult XMLexport () {
        Object obj = db.IntegerLists.Include("Integers");
        Serialize(obj);
        return View();
    }
    public static string Serialize(Object obj)
    {
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, obj);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.GetBuffer());
    }
```

At the line

```
serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, obj);
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[[IntegerSorter.Models.IntegerList,     IntegerSorter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' is an invalid collection type since it does not have a valid Add method with parameter of type 'IntegerSorter.Models.IntegerList'.
```

Can somebody advise me where and how to implement the Add method?

**Update:**

Changing:

```
Object obj = db.IntegerLists.Include("Integers");
```

to

```
Object obj = db.IntegerLists.Include("Integers").ToList();
```

results in:

```
Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.IntegerList_62F0932A6DFC38A25629DF18911498D42B3785A93BCE8B8D2F77C3363B3F4200' with data contract name 'IntegerList_62F0932A6DFC38A25629DF18911498D42B3785A93BCE8B8D2F77C3363B3F4200:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line:

`Object obj = db.IntegerLists.Include("Integers");`

To this:

`Object obj = db.IntegerLists.Include("Integers").ToList();`

This will cause the database query to run and give you a `List<IntegerList>` instead of a `DbQuery<IntegerList>`. This should then provide what the serializer wants (because it has a `Add(IntegerList)` method available as requested by the error).

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted Greg's answer but feel I should detail the subsequent issues I had to work through:

```
Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.IntegerList_62F0932A6DFC38A25629DF18911498D42B3785A93BCE8B8D2F77C3363B3F4200' with data contract name 'IntegerList_62F0932A6DFC38A25629DF18911498D42B3785A93BCE8B8D2F77C3363B3F4200:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
```

was solved with:

```
Context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

and then:

```
Object graph for type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[IntegerSorter.Models.Integer, IntegerSorter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.
```

was solved by decorating the navigation property on the Integer class as below:

```
[IgnoreDataMember]
public virtual IntegerList IntegerList { get; set; }
```